# to display array values from database single field

Tags: php, mysql

I  have 3 queries like:

1.

```
SELECT `id`, `state_id`, `city_id`, `spaid` FROM `city_place`
```

2.

```
SELECT `state_id`, `state` FROM `states`
```

3.

```
SELECT `city_id`, `city`, `state_id` FROM `cities`
```

using `implode()` while uploading `if city_place.state_id=11(bangalore)` 
I stored only ids city_place.city_id as (12(silk board),13(madiwala),...)like that. then after uploading I want to display city names only separated by(,) 
where `city_place.city_id='11'` and `city_place.spaid='234'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do.
After using implode() you schould use explode() and create an array. Then you can parse elements of this array again.
I think you could construct more complex SELECT statement with JOINT or use msyql_fetch_array to get arrays and then use them but like I said, I don't know what you exactly want to do.

Answer (score 0):

query for fetch record....
if u want to check any condition then add condition end of the query..

$qry ="SELECT cp.id, spaid, s.state, c.city 
from city_place AS cp
LEFT JOIN state AS s on cp.state_id=s.state_id
LEFT JOIN cities AS c ON cp.city_id=c.city_id";

in this query u will fetch id and spaid from city place table, city from city table and state from state table of particular record.